# Interior.PatternTintAndShade Property

Tags: excel, vba, xlsx

I am working on excel sheets with large amount of cell pattern based data. I am trying to read the values of these cell patterns and store that info in another sheet. But I am unable to do so as there is no function available to do this in Excel. Please help.

Comment: You might try a Copy, then Paste Special, Formats.

Answer (score 0):

As per your title, it appears that you want VBA.
Now, it is not clear if you want to copy [`Interior.Pattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835883.aspx), [`Interior.PatternTintAndShade`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192986.aspx), or perhaps something else.

The code you need is something like

```
Dim wssrc as Worksheet, wstrg as Worksheet
Dim rngsrc as Range, clsrc as Range, cltrg as Range
Set rngsrc = <what you want>
For Each clsrc in rngsrc
    Set cltrg = wstrg.Range(clsrc.Address)
    cltrg.Interior.PatternTintAndShade = clsrc.Interior.PatternTintAndShade
Next clsrc
```

(PS: I do not currently have a system with Excel, so this code may need little adjustments).

Other option that perhaps works for you is: first copy, and then use
[`Range.PasteSpecial` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx), with the first argument [xlPasteFormats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425.aspx).
This is the VBA method for *Edit* -> *Paste Special* (see comment by Jeeped).